# Querying the currently visible layer in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

My map has several layers, and I have a check box list that can turn individual layers on and off (ie. hidden/visible).

I'd like to have querying capability, but with so many layers, I think the easiest way might be to only allow querying on whatever layer is visible, and if there are a few visible, only the top layer is queryable.

The tutorials I've seen are only for querying one layer. How would I go about doing this for multiple layers and for only those that are visible? This is a poor attempt, and only works for one layer:

```
  var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {
    var features = [];
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
      features.push(feature);
    });
    var container = document.getElementById('information');
    if (features.length > 0) {
      var info = [];
      for (var i = 0, ii = features.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        info.push(features[i].get('County_Name'))+info.push(features[i].get('Name'))
      }
      container.innerHTML = info.join('- ') || '(unknown)';
    } else {
      container.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    }
  };

        map.on('click', function(evt) {
    var pixel = evt.pixel;
    displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
  });
```

Comment: The documentation says by default all visible layers are considered with `forEachFeatureAtPixel` and the default `opt_layerFilter` (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel). Are you sure all features have the same properties (in your case 'County_Name' & 'Name')?

Comment: can't you filter using 'layer' parameter in forEachFeatureAtPixel?